# How to sync payment from salesforce to netsuite without a credit card

Tags: salesforce, payment, netsuite

I want to sync a record in Netsuite from Salesforce. The payment was created in Salesforce and It has a token details of a Credit Card, also last 4 digits of the card. I want to sync the payment in Netsuite. But if I choose "paymentmethod" = "Credit Card" then it asking for the whole Credit Card Number which must be 13-20 digit long. How to turn off that validation? I just want to sync the payment not the credit card details. 
Looking forward for your ideas and suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: May I know why this got down-vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there is now to turn off this validation. There is option called accounting list and added a new value there. See the below attached screenshot.[accounting list in Netsuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m)

[Add new payment method in Netsuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrmnG.png)1yVM.png

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to turn the validation off.  What you can do is select a different Payment Method, or use a custom field to identify payments made with Credit Cards in Salesforce.